# Selecting items from list of objects based on values of generic object attributes

Tags: python

### **Background**

Let's say I have some class `Info` which stores bunch of attributes defined by user such as:

```
class Info:    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)
```

and I have a list of `Info` instances, let's say:

```
all_keys = [Info(a=1, b='y', c=0),
            Info(a=2, b='y', c=1),
            Info(a=3, b='n', c=2),
            Info(a=2, b='y', c=3)]
```

I want to select from the list `all_keys` items based on some criteria on `a`, `b`, `c`. I made the following function:

```
def keys_with(all_keys, **kwargs):
    out = []
    for info in all_keys:
        flag = 1
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if info[k] != v:
               flag = 0
               break
        if flag:
            out.append(info)
    return out
```

### **Expected usage and output**

I want to do something like: `my_keys = keys_with(all_keys, a=2, b='y')` . The current function `keys_with` given the desired output:

```
[Info(c=1, a=2, b=y), Info(c=3, a=2, b=y)]
```

### Question

The function `keys_with()` is ugly for something so simple: it uses a flag, nested loops, and looks very non-pythonic. I am sure there is a much better way to write it more compactly and more pythonically. I appreciate any help or hints!

Comment: You can use a list comprehension, but that would be too compact for my taste. Instead, use a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). That will get rid of `out` and `flag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
def keys_with(all_keys, **kwargs):
    def matches(info):
        """
        Iterates over all `kwargs` outside and returns True 
        only if all the key/values within kwargs are present in info.
        """
        return all(getattr(info, x) == y for x, y in kwargs.items())

    return [info for info in all_keys if matches(info)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess `all` was all I need!